# Why react-hooks/rules-of-hooks doesn't throw error?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslintrc

From my understanding, hooks can only be used within custom hooks or functional components. However, even though the below code snippet has the react-hooks/rules-of-hooks installed, using `useAlias` inside the `ClaimMonitorStore`, which is not a functional component, doesn't seem to cause any errors. Can you explain why no exception is thrown in this case?

```
export const ClaimMonitorStore = (unifiedOnboardingStatus: TUnifiedOnboardingStatusStore) => ({
    claimMonitorsStatus: RenderingStatus.Ready,
    claimMonitorsErrMsg: "",
    searchText: "",
    alias: useAlias(),
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the ESLint rule can't distinguish between a vanilla function and a "React component". I quote component here because a (functional) component is just a function. There's not an obvious way to determine if it's a component or a non-component vanilla function, so the rule just checks for the use of hooks inside of functions.

It's also because your function starts with a capital letter. Change it to lowercase to gain more insight from the linting error:

> React Hook "useAlias" is called in function "claimMonitorStore" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use".eslintreact-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Comment: @weiwang You could click the empty check mark next to the answer to mark it as correct, to help others find the answer in the future, and to give me fake internet points.